# Topos of sheaves on a scheme considered as a functor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, schemes, topos-theory

The spectrum of a ring $R$ can be defined as $\operatorname{Spec} R := \operatorname{Hom}(R, -)\colon \mathrm{fpRing} \to \mathrm{Set}$ ($\mathrm{fpRing}$ are commutative finitely presentable rings). Is it possible to quickly extract the topos of sheaves $\operatorname{Sh}(\operatorname{Spec} R)$ directly from this definition, bypassing the construction of a locally ringed space?

For example, you can take the slice topos in the topos of sheaves on the [Zariski site](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Zariski+site) (hardly this is the answer, but this is an example of what the answer could sound like).

Comment: Do you mean finitely presented?

Comment: Of course, thank you! Corrected.

Comment: The slice topos produces sheaves on the big Zariski site of the scheme, I think, and the issue is you want sheaves on the small Zariski site (i.e on the underlying topological space) - does that sound right?

Comment: I believe that if you consider the category of Sheaves in a Zariski topology that are over $Spec R$ and locally isomorphic to $Spec R$ (where locally is taken in the sense of the Zariski pretopology) you should get the small Zariski topos (that is, Sh(Spec R) ). That should work with any scheme in fact.

Comment: TeX note: `\operatorname` should be used in place of `\mathrm` for things that are semantically operators.  Note the difference between $\mathrm{Spec} R$ `\mathrm{Spec} R` and $\operatorname{Spec} R$ `\operatorname{Spec} R`.  I have edited accordingly.  (By the way, there is a special syntax for defining `\operatorname`s to be used repeatedly: `\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}`.)

Comment: In functorial algebraic geometry you only get the category of quasi-coherent sheaves for free. I don't think it works with the category of all sheaves. Notice also that the notion of a sheaf then only refers to the underlying topological space of the scheme.

Comment: "Notice also that the notion of a sheaf then only refers to the underlying topological space of the scheme" Of course, this is exactly my motivation. I am interested in finding such a definition for repetition in a certain similar context, where there is (at first glance) a natural definition of spectrum as a functor, but how exactly one should define the underlying space (by which I am happy to understand an arbitrary Grothendieck topos) is not clear.